# EPERM Error using fs.rename()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code:

```
exports.post_handler = function(req, res) {
    var photo = req.files.image;
    console.log(photo);
    console.log(__dirname);

    fs.readFile(photo.path, function(err, data) { //I use the path module to join the image path strings
        fs.rename(path.join(__dirname, "public/temp"), path.join(__dirname,"public/images"), function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect("/");
            }
            else {
                console.log("file " + photo.name + "written to uploads folder");
                res.redirect("/home");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I'm trying to move an uploaded image file from  my `temp` folder to my `uploads` folder. I'm using the `fs` module to do this. After granting full permissions to both files to all users on my PC, I'm getting the following error:

```
{ [Error: EPERM, rename 'dir\public\temp']
  errno: 50,
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'dir\\public\\temp' }
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your code is trying to do is rename the `public/temp` directory to `public/images`. `public/images` presumably already exists, so you're getting that error. In other words, nowhere in there are you moving the image, you're instead 'moving' (renaming) the directory `public/temp` to `public/images`.

You have to use `photo.path` instead. Use it as the first parameter and then perhaps the second parameter should `path.join` images directory to `path.basename(photos.path)`.